# How can i use jquery using the MVC?

Tags: php, jquery, phalcon

this is my SignupController.php code:

```
    <?php class SignupController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller {

public function indexAction()
{

}

public function registerAction()
{

$user = new Users();

    //Store and check for errors
    $success = $user->save($this->request->getPost(), array('name', 'email'));

    if ($success) {
        echo "k";

    } else {
        echo "Sorry, the following problems were generated: ";
        foreach ($user->getMessages() as $message) {
            echo $message->getMessage(), "<br/>";
        }
    }

    $this->view->disable();
}  }
```

then this is my index.php inside my signup folder:

```
   <html>
   <head><title>trial</title> <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/ext.js"></script>
   <body>
   <div id="signup/-feedback"></div>
   <form id="signupForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="signup/register">
   <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"  >
   <td colspan="3" align="center" height="50"><strong>Registration form</strong></td>  <br />
   <tr>
   <th>Name:</th>
   <td><input name="name" type="Variable" class="input2" id="name"  /></td>
   <div id="underInput" />
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <th>Email:</th>
   <td><input name="email" type="Variable" class="input2" id="email" /></td>
   </tr>

  <td>&nbsp;</td>

  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register" />
  <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Clear" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  </body>
  </html>
```

this is my ext.js:

```
$('signupForm').submit(function(){
    var name = $ ('#name').val();
    $('#signup_feedback').html('Registration success', + name + 'has been registered. You may now do 10 cartwheels XD');
});
```

what should i do?

this is my index.php in my public folder:

```
    try {

//Register an autoloader
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
$loader->registerDirs(array(
    '../app/controllers/',
    '../app/models/'
))->register();

//Create a DI
$di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

//Setup the database service
$di->set('db', function(){
    return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
        "host" => "localhost",
        "username" => "root",
        "password" => "123",
        "dbname" => "test_db"
    ));
});

//Setup the view component
$di->set('view', function(){
    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
    $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');
    return $view;
});

//Setup a base URI so that all generated URIs include the "tutorial" folder
$di->set('url', function(){
    $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
    $url->setBaseUri('/');
    return $url;
});

//Handle the request
$application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);

echo $application->handle()->getContent();

} catch(\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
 echo "PhalconException: ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

is there a way that i'll resolve this~~~ thank you so much

Comment: i think you forgot something......$('#signupForm') signupform is an ID so dont forget to add '#'

Comment: i already changed it but no matter what i do it always redirect to register. i want to try the code that won't reload my page but all the data that i input will be registered to my db. it'll just show a note that it was registered using jquery. thank you in advance :)

Comment: thats a much more clear explenation.... in that case remove the "<form>" tags and give your button an ID. when some1 click on it trigger whatever you wanna do in javascript (for example make an ajax call to do the registering)

Comment: if i removed the <form> and put id in my button, for example i put "boom" as my id in my button, is that will i put in $('#boom') instead of $('#signupForm') ?

Comment: yeah something like that, go try it if you get stuck on it i can write a quick example for you

Comment: @lauw it's still not working it's still redirecting to the register page. i need to resolve this part :
public function registerAction()
{

$user = new Users();

    //Store and check for errors
    $success = $user->save($this->request->getPost(), array('name', 'email'));

    if ($success) {
        echo "k";

    } else {
        echo "Sorry, the following problems were generated: ";
        foreach ($user->getMessages() as $message) {
            echo $message->getMessage(), "<br/>";
        }
    }

    $this->view->disable();
}  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're actually asking here. But based on the comments am I correct in assuming that you want to store the user in the DB without actually loading the register page and just show a message?

If so, I think the issue actually seems to be with your javascript:

```
   $('#signupForm').submit(function(){
   var name = $ ('#name').val();
    $('#signup_feedback').html('Registration success', + name + 'has been registered. You may now do 10 cartwheels XD');
 });
```

All your actually doing here is assigning a value to the name variable and then changing the html of the element with id of signup_feedback. You're not actually stopping the action of the form. You can test this by adding an alert in to this method, you will see the alert fire then redirect. You need to use AJAX here to post the name variable to the register form and then prevent the default action of the form, thus stopping the redirect

Something like the following pseudo code

```
     $('#signupForm').submit(function(e){ //note the e variable this is the event
     e.preventDefault();
     var name = $('#name').val(); // get the value of name from the form
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
           url: "signup/register",
           data: { name: name }
        })
       .done(function( msg ) {
             $('#signup_feedback').html('Registration success', + name + 'has been registered. You may now do 10 cartwheels XD');
        });
     });
```

full docs for the AJAX function are here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

As I say that was just pseudo code so it probably needs a bit of tweaking, but it should point you in the right direction. An alternative to e.preventDefault() is just to add

```
   return false;
```

to the bottom of your submit method

Comment: If this was the correct answer could you please accept it. Thanks